# Missing Axiom support in spring-ws 4.0.0-M1

Tags: java, spring-ws

Is Axiom support planned for spring-ws 4.x?  I tried upgrading my spring-ws 2.2.4 project to spring-ws 4.0.0-M1 (since 3.x is at End Of Support) and noticed that org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom package is missing from spring-ws-core module.  Reference Documentation still mentions AxiomSoapMessageFactory.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the current documentation still mentions Axiom as a solution even while it appears to be removed seems to be an error and is quite irritating indeed. In December [a blog post about updated samples](https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/02/spring-ws-samples-upgraded-for-spring-boot-3-0) was published that mentions that support for Axiom was removed from spring-ws and mentions some details as to why:

> Axiom doesn’t support Jakarta EE 9+
>
> Spring Web Services 4.0 had to, unfortunately, drop its support for Apache Axiom. Its most recently version (1.4) still taps the old version of Java EE Activation, not the Jakarta EE version.

Would be curious to hear whether you found a solution for this situation, or which one you chose. Using the `AxiomSoapMessageFactory` was a convenient way for me to utilise a StAX based processing with spring-ws that I am now sort of missing.